# Add Library To PHP Set-up

Tags: apache-http-server, php

I compiled PHP into Apache(version 1.3.37) using apxs, if I need to recompile PHP (to add some more libraries) do I need to re-compile Apache as well?

Comment: 1.37? 1.3.7? 1.3.37? ... Wait, why are you even still running httpd 1.3?

Comment: Sorry, lazy typing. I'm am using 1.3.37 - the reason is because I also use Mason, which doesn't support Apache 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I just go for it (I have back-ups).
For all to know, if PHP is compiled into Apache as a .so you can re-make PHP with whatever configuration you want. Just don't forget to stop and start Apache again. 
*Note: issuing a restart command won't work.*